# VSCode Snippet Extension Doesn't Work in Strings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

Snippets don't work in Strings in my Extension, but that's where they're supposed to be used. Any idea? They start with $. Could that be why?

Comment: Could you please give some more details?!?

Comment: Okay, so. My code snippet has this prefix. $title, and it only works outside of "strings", \`etc...`, and i want to make it work inside of the strings.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/7CPNVR3p

Comment: https://postimg.cc/k22fHMLb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code snippet and insert in your `settings.json` to allow Visual Studio Code to show the EXT snippets in strings.

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    },
```

Comment: I need it pre-activated by the Extension if Possible whitin any setting in it.

Comment: Will this work for pre-activated? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configurationDefaults